# windows batch read file and run command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need some help with windows batch script.

I have a list of hostnames in a text file `nodes.txt` that I want batch file to read then run following commands for each hostname found in `nodes.txt`

Here are the commands to run

```
ovdeploy -upload -file "C:\Users\AG\scopemsgs" -targetdir "c:\temp" -host

ovdeploy -cmd "move c:\temp\scopemsgs 'C:\Program Files\HP\HP BTO Software\msg\C\'" -host

ovdeploy -cmd "ovpacmd start" -host

ovdeploy -cmd "perfstat -p" -host
```

after `-host` script should put hostname
for example

```
ovdeploy -upload -file "C:\Users\AG\scopemsgs" -targetdir "c:\temp" -host node123.com
```

I tried this

```
for /f %%i in (nodes.txt) do set node=%%i

ovdeploy -upload -file "C:\Users\AG\scopemsgs" -targetdir "c:\temp" -host node
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%i in (nodes.txt) do (
 ovdeploy ... -host %%i
 ovdeploy ... -host %%i
 ovdeploy ... -host %%i
)
```

`%%i` will be assigned each value found in the file in turn.